# Clone curl with python-requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

This curl request works:

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' --inient_id":"?CLIENT_ID??", "client_secret":"CLIENT_SECRET", "grant_type":"client_credentials", "scope": "anonymous"}' https://auth2do2go.fitdev.ru/oauth/token
```

This python request does not:

```
data = {
    "client_id": "CLIENT_ID", 
    "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "anonymous"
}

url = "https://auth2do2go.fitdev.ru/oauth/token/"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
print(r.content)
```

Why it this happening?

I've tried data=json.dumps(data) instead of data=data, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't JSON:

```
import json
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
```

Also, don't post live credentials here ;)

Comment: As I said, I've tried it. I also tried POST instead, it just does not work.

Comment: It appeared to work for me. (200 vs 504 response). What error are you getting? What is the response given for you? Can you verify the fields are correct? Try changing `data=` to `params=`?